# Replace property file in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I tried searching couple of posts/articles/forum but seems my questions is still unanswered. I am looking for a way in spring boot to replace application property based on some flag. Here is is what i am trying to do :

1. I have file called products.properties in spring boot application where in my application properties are defined.
2. I also have file called products.properties.replace which replaces based on environment like QA,Dev all property values.

Now i want two replace file because i have two types of server whose values will be different & replace file already have environment based values.

Can we have multiple replace files & by environment variable can i make that replace file picked by spring application.

Comment: Have you tried using Profiles https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: @SimonMartinelli this is an interesting use case, spring profiles can not solve this. This is something like play framework provides, you can extends the properties file.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli My code is already working with enviroment like prod,dev in .replace file we have like property[dev]=Value...property[QA]=Value hence enviroment is not problem. My Question is what if i want this enviroment as well as another flag which take completely different .replace file based on Server A OR Server B delpoyment

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to acheive and why this can't be done with profiles.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Ar u available on chat